# Remove blobs less than a specific size MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have the original gray scale image below which I dilated and eroded in order to get the binary image.  I have two questions:

1) How can I remove the shadows / extra noise (Examples of what I am referring to are circled red part of the images)?
2) In the binary image, the black singular beads are larger than they should be and the white ones are smaller.  Other than eroding and dilating, is there a way to normalize their sizes? (see circled blue for clarification).

I've done some work with regionprops, but has not yielded what I need.

[image: See image for clarification]

Answer (score 1):

you can try use [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) to remove small objects from binary image.

Comment: Very nice.  Didn't think of that.  Cheers.